# UISearchController & Segue

Tags: xcode, segue, uisearchcontroller

I am learning the UISearchController and found that I encountered the following problems.

1. When I typed the text in the Search Bar, the records were filtered and displayed properly. When I clicked the record, it supposed to segue to another ViewController to show the detail view. But it returned to the filtered result.
   [image: Main Screen]
   [image: Type the info in the Search Bar]

[image: Clicked the first record]

2. The second problem is after I clicked the record, it displayed the information of the unfiltered record instead of the filtered record.
   [image: It should show GMT BLRO]

```
class Method2VC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var item = [Item]()
    var searchResults = [Item]()
    var searchController: UISearchController!

    var isSearchBarEmpty: Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        // Setup Search Bar information
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true

        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "输入搜索信息"
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = true

        fetchData()

    }

    func fetchData() {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        // let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
        let modelSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "model", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [modelSort]
        do {
            let fetchedResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            item = fetchedResults

        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destination as! DetailVC
                destinationController.item = !isSearchBarEmpty ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : item[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableView Datasource
extension Method2VC: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if !isSearchBarEmpty {
            return searchResults.count
        } else {
            return item.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2", for: indexPath)

        // Determine the data - Original Data or SearchResults Data
        let model = !isSearchBarEmpty ? searchResults[indexPath.row] : item[indexPath.row]

        // Configure Cell
        cell.textLabel?.text = model.model
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UISearchResultUpdating
extension Method2VC: UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if !isSearchBarEmpty {
            if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
                filterContent(for: searchText)
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    func filterContent(for searchText: String) {
        searchResults = item.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
            if let model = item.model {
                let isMatch = model.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
                return isMatch
            }
            return false
        })
    }
}
```

Please advise.

Best regards,
Galen

Comment: Rather than posting huge screenshots please post the relevant code.

Comment: Hi Vadian, Code added. Thanks! Galen

Comment: @GFONG what is the code that you have in didSelectRow? If this is IB you need to post a photo of your storyboard and the segue between the searchvc and the destinationvc

Comment: I did not have didSelectRow. I control+dragged the TableView Cell to the destinationVC to create the Segue in Storyboard.

Comment: If not using the Search, I can click the row and go to the destinationVC without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation To false.

For my case I use dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation. It is deprecated.

As I am using the same ViewController, therefore the above setting has to set to false.